# Moodle 1.8.1 PHP Issue

Tags: php, moodle

I am working with an old version of Moodle (`1.8.1`) using `PHP 5.4` an error occurs when clicking on a link to an assignment or trying to add a new activity. I am getting the following error:

```
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/myduicla/public_html/online/course/modedit.php on line 141
```

The following line causes the error above:

```
$mform=& new $mformclassname($form->instance, $cousesection, ((isset($cm))?$cm:null));
```

The above snippet is from the following section:

```
$mformclassname = 'mod_'.$module->name.'_mod_form';
$cousesection=isset($cw->section)?$cw->section:$section;
$mform=& new $mformclassname($form->instance, $cousesection, ((isset($cm))?$cm:null));
$mform->set_data($form);
```

I tried to fix the problem by removing the `&`

```
$mform= new $mformclassname($form->instance, $cousesection, ((isset($cm))?$cm:null));
```

After changing this the error turned in `interal server error`, when clicking on a lesson or adding an activity. The error:

https://www.example.com/online/mod/assignment/view.php?id=9657

```
HTTP ERROR 500 This page isn’t working www.example.com is currently unable to handle this request.
```

Comment: I edited the question to clarify it, I formatted the code snippets and reordered them to give more context

Comment: For error of  deprecated $mform=& new $mformclassname remove the & character....so give error 500